# Using Kubernetes Container as a Custom NAT instance?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, iptables, nat

[GCP](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) used to have a documentation that explained about using [Google Compute instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute) as a custom NAT Device, it is now deprecated and deleted as per [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway).

Basically it had a list of commands that used `sysctl` and `iptables` commands in order to forward some traffic received to a specific destination IP.

The commands looked like below:

```sh
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination xx.xxx.xxx.xx
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

I have a working compute instance that is being used as a NAT device to forward some traffic from some IPs to a specific destination. This is done with the help of [Google Cloud Routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes). Example:

```sh
gcloud compute routes create $EXAMPLE-ROUTE-NAME \
    --network $NETWORK-NAME \
    --destination-range 1.1.1.1 \
    --next-hop-instance $CUSTOM-NAT-INSTANCE-NAME \
    --next-hop-instance-zone $CUSTOM-NAT-INSTANCE-ZONE \
    --tags $TAG-NAME \
    --priority 800
```

This way, when all the VM instance in "${NETWORK-NAME}" with the tag "$TAG-NAME" try to send a request to "1.1.1.1", this custom route forwards the traffic to "$CUSTOM-NAT-INSTANCE-NAME" and this instance acts as a NAT and forwards the traffic to "xx.xxx.xxx.xx".

I understand the concept of "[Google Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview)" and how easy it is to set it up, but because of some limitations, we have to use a custom NAT.

Now my question is, can we setup a custom NAT on [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-is-kubernetes) container? There is no `sysctl` command inside the container (as expected) and `securityContext.sysctls.name: net.ipv4.ip_forward` is not allowed in GKE.

Is it possible to use a Kubernetes Container as a NAT device?

Comment: I think you can use ` ip-masq-agent` to achieve that. Similar to how it's described in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gke-address-management-nat-for-cidr-block)

Comment: ip-masq-agent won't help with ip forwarding and nating. I don't know if this can be done or if there is a hard limitation, but it will be complicated because of the networking layer of GKE with outgoing traffic

Comment: AFAIK - No. The primary reason is that you cannot enable `IP Forwarding`. This is required to prevent Source / Destination IP address checks. IP packets will be dropped without that that feature being enabled.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gke-address-management-nat-for-cidr-block-tutorial this will help you make custom NAT in GKE using iptable